# How to resize tmux panes inside tty

Tags: linux, tmux, tty

I'm not sure if I used the right term, but by "tty" I understand the console that you can switch to using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> key combination. `echo $TERM` points to `linux`. Anyway, when I enter the tmux mode I can make several panes. I can also switch between them without problems but I can't resize them. I'm able to do so in the graphic mode (X11) by pressing <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (tmux prefix) and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>,<kbd>→</kbd>,<kbd>↑</kbd>,<kbd>↓</kbd> arrows.

Does anyone know how to do the same under the tty console?

Comment: They're both terminals.  The former is a _virtual terminal_ (sometimes also called a _virtual console_) and the latter (employed by a program such as `xterm`, `konsole`, `lxterminal`, or `gnome-terminal`) is a _pseudo-terminal_.  Help the answerers and edit your question with the value of the `TERM` environment variable in the respective shells (before you invoke `tmux`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question also on tmux mailing list, and I got the following answer:

> When you press a non-text key or key-sequence, your terminal
>   translates that into some particular sequence of characters. For
>   example, if I open a new gnome-terminal, run "cat" and press keys, I
>   can see that left-arrow sends "^[[D", while ctrl+left-arrow sends
>   "^[[1;5D".
>
> I believe the ability to send modifiers (ctrl, alt, shift) with
>   arrow-keys is a feature added by xterm and copied by other
>   terminal-emulators, it's not part of the original VT100/VT220
>   feature-set. Which is to say, if you run "cat" in a terminal and
>   pressing ctrl+left-arrow results in "^[[D" on your screen, then you're
>   out of luck.
>
> In particular, the Linux console is a very limited and
>   not-particularly-xterm-compatible terminal, and it doesn't surprise me
>   that it doesn't support ctrl+arrow keys.

So, the only way to resize panes under tty is to rebind keys:

```
bind-key -r < resize-pane -L 3
bind-key -r > resize-pane -R 3
bind-key -r + resize-pane -U 1
bind-key -r = resize-pane -D 1
```

Comment: Using equal sign may not be recommended, as it does have a default action ("choose-buffer") in my version of tmux (OpenBSD 5.0).  Use Ctrl-B an dthen ? to see what is bound, and choose something unused.  For quicker testing, you don't really need to bind.  You can just use Ctrl-B, then colon, then "resizep -D" (to move down one), or similar variations (Ctrl-B, then ":resizep -L 3") would move Left three.  Slower in the long term, but quicker instant success/test.  "-U 1" specifies two options that are both default.